# Laravel: How to order date, change the date format and group by the date?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a date list in the database and from the list, I get the month and despite lay in the dropdown. Right now it works but I don't know how to order the date by ascending before I change the format. Below is the date list:

| date |
| --- |
| 2021-08-02 |
| 2021-09-30 |
| 2021-08-01 |
| 2021-09-06 |
| 2021-11-05 |

Right now in the dropdown display

|  |
| --- |
| August |
| November |
| September |

It should be

|  |
| --- |
| August |
| September |
| November |

Here's my eloquent to display the dropdown

```
$date = DateList::where('id',$id->id)->select(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M')) as newDate"))->groupBy('newDate')->get();
```

I have a search around but still could not find the answer on how to get the correct way to order the date before changing it to the format. Hope anyone can help.

Comment: add an `orderBy('date', 'ASC')` in your query

Comment: The `DATE_FORMAT` cast shouldnt be necessary if you just have a complete timestamp as a column. Simply order by that column and it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use laravel's awesome collection api?

```
DateList::where('id',$id->id)
  ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
  // uncomment the below line if you're concerned with performance
  // ->select('date')
  ->pluck('date')
  ->map(function($date) {
    return $date->format("F");
  })
  ->unique();
```

Comment: thank you so much! But in my case, I got error "Call to a member function format() on string" so I modify it to DateList::where('id',$id->id)->orderBy('date', 'ASC')->pluck('date')->map(function($date) {Carbon::parse($date)->format('F'); })->unique(); It works now :)

Comment: @GarfieldJunior Nice catch! But if you get date field as string, something is wrong with your migration and model class. Laravel should automatically cast timestamp and datetime fields to Carbon\Carbon.

Comment: If you don't want to touch migration again, you can also cast field values to date automatically. Refer to this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Comment: thank you for the info. But I set the date datatype as DATE, not DATETIME. Is it related to the result that I get it as string?

Comment: I don't think so. If you didn't create tables with migration then there should be problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey GarfieldJuniorI couldn't think any way to implement the above but the way I would suggest is to fetch month's number instead of name and sort it then map the array/Collection to Months name,
for mapping thing either you can user index array of like

```
$monthNames=[
  1=>"JANUARY",
  2=>"FABRUARY
]
```

OR

you can use by creating a dummy date by months Number using [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) method of php, It takes format type of string as first argument and second $timestamp
`$format ='F'` ,
and 
`$timestamp=mktime(0,0,0,$monthNumber)`
ref [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)
so in short your if you get sorted months number Array like this (I'm using date method not indexed Array)

```
$monthsArray=[1,2,3];
$monthNames=array_map(
      function($monthNumber){
           return date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNumber));
           }
     ,$monthsArray);
```

your output will look like this

```
[
     "January",
     "February",
     "March",
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do order by from your query like this

```
$date = DateList::where('id',$id->id)
->select(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M')) as newDate"))
->groupBy('newDate')
->orderBy('newDate', 'ASC')
->get();
```